# MySQLのmy.iniがない

Tags: mysql

MySQLの設定ファイルが見つかりません。

ローカル環境にMySQLを入れようとしています。
[参考1](https://www.webdlab.com/local/local-mysql-4/)
このあたりを参考に、MySQLをダウンロードしファイルを解凍後
コマンドプロンプトで`mysqld --install`を実行し、インストールしました。

設定ファイルを編集しようとすると元のmy-default.iniが存在せず、
[参考2](https://qiita.com/Nemy/items/4544d7d74574dd32529a)にProgramDataにあると記載されていますが、ProgramDataの中にMySQLというディレクトリがありません。

他、どこにあると考えられるでしょうか。
ご教授ください。
環境
windows10
MySQL8.0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 前置き

参考にされたページはどちらも2～3年前程度の古い記事である点は注意が必要です。
現時点での最新版は`8.0.20` で、確かにZIPファイルには `my-default.ini` が含まれていませんでした。

しかし、参照された記事で言及しているのは `5.7` で古いバージョンです。
(MySQLの場合、バージョン番号の増え方が特殊で v5.6 -> v5.7 -> v8.0 の順になります)

また、実行したコマンド `mysqld --install` はあくまで **サービスの登録** であり、一般的なアプリケーションのインストールとは少し意味合いが違います。

[Windows のサービスとして MySQL を起動する](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/windows-start-service.html)

> #### サービスのインストール
>
> サーバーをこのコマンドを使用してサービスとしてインストールします。
>
> ```
> C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld" --install
> ```

---

#### 回答

オプションファイルが無ければ **作成** しましょう。オプションファイルが無くても MySQL はデフォルト値で動作しますし、オプションファイルが自動で作成されるのはインストーラを使用した場合のようです。
(`my-default.ini` がアーカイブに同梱されていたのは恐らく `v5.6` 辺りまで)

ZIPファイルからのインストール手順はヘルプで以下のように記載されています。

[非インストール Zip アーカイブを使用して Microsoft Windows に MySQL をインストールする](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/windows-install-archive.html)

> MySQL を Zip アーカイブからインストールする手順は次のとおりです。
>
> 1. アーカイブを任意のインストールディレクトリに抽出する
> 2. **オプションファイルを作成する**
> 3. MySQL のサーバータイプを選択する
> 4. MySQL Server を起動する
> 5. デフォルトのユーザーアカウントをセキュアにする

また、オプションファイルの配置場所はヘルプの [オプションファイルの使用](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/option-files.html) を参考にしてください。

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld" --install`を実行すると、指定されたパスが見つからないと表示されます。
`mysqld --install`後に表示されているbinの中身を指定してみると、すでにインストールされています、と表示されます。
これはどういう状態なのでしょうか。インストールまでは完了していたと考えてもいいのでしょうか。

Comment: パスはあくまで一例なので、実際の環境に合わせて適時読み替えてください。(質問文にはどのようにインストールしたのか具体的なパスが記載されていないので、残念ながら第三者からは分かりません) / "既にインストールされています" に対しては回答本文に書いたとおり **Windowsのサービス** としてインストールされた状態です。ZIPファイルをダウンロードしたのであれば、インストール自体は適当なフォルダに解凍するだけで終わりです。